# SystemColors versus ProfessionalColors

Tags: .net, winforms

In the past, anytime I needed a Windows Color in my Windows development, I selected from the [SystemColors Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors), which is part of the [System.Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows) namespace.

Today, purely by mistake, I hit the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key after typing in `Pr`, expecting [Intellisense](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx) to do that heavy lifting and select [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process) (from the [System.Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics) namespace) for me.

There I was, starring at something I had never noticed before: [ProfessionalColors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dx2csf2.aspx).

I explored **ProfessionalColors Class** a while on MSDN where I quickly found it is part of the [System.Windows.Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.aspx) namespace, but I was not able to see much more. That was when I looked up **SystemColors** to see where it was different.

Nothing jumps out at me. **ProfessionalColors** does not appear to add any functionality over **SystemColors**.

I suppose `System.Windows` could offer a larger set of colors that `System.Windows.Forms` cannot display (or vice versa), but I was not able to confirm anything with a search or imagine where a Window would use a color that was not part of a Windows Form.

Does anyone have any light to shed on these two color classes?

## Why are there two separate classes and what is the difference between these them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A part from the different set of predefined colors available, it seems that the static constructor of ProfessionalColors subscribes to [UserPreferenceChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.userpreferencechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event. Also there is an internal table that keeps all the colors instead of building a new color for every call.

```
static ProfessionalColors()
{
    SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged += new UserPreferenceChangedEventHandler(ProfessionalColors.OnUserPreferenceChanged);
    SetScheme();
}
```

This is the code that return MenuBorder in ProfessionalColor

```
public static Color MenuBorder
{
    get
    {
        return ColorTable.MenuBorder;
    }
}
```

While this is the code for WindowText in SystemColor

```
public static Color WindowText
{
    get
    {
        return new Color(KnownColor.WindowText);
    }
}
```

Comment: [KnownColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.knowncolor.aspx)? How many of these collections are there?

Answer (score 3):

Their primary use is in drawing the ToolStrip container and controls.

See [How to: Customize Colors in ToolStrip Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229724%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)